# Controller within another Controller

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to instantiate a Controller class within another controller class using the Yii Framework

For example I have controller Student and and method actionShow of class student I have the following

```
public function actionShow()
    {  

        $student = $this->loadStudent();

        $studentContact = new Student_ContactController;

        //Checking if there was an ajax request
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
            $this->renderPartial('show',array(
                'student'=>$student,

            ));
        }else{
            $this->render('show',array(
                'student'=>$student,
            ));
        }



    }
```

Is it possible to include this action in the method $studentContact = new Student_ContactController;

Getting errors, :-(

Comment: It is more likely you have a design problem, try refactor your code.
Data should be Model not controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the Yii framework, but as it is an MVC framework, then getting data should be part of the model, therefore $studentContact should be an instance of a model, not of a controller.

If you really want to instanciate an instance of a controller then call the constructor with brackets:

```
    $studentContact = new Student_ContactController();
```